# Google calendar add-on - Prevent multiple event triggering

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-calendar-api, add-on

I am developing a calendar add-on. According to my use-case, the add-on needs to be updated for the below scenarios.

1. Once the user opens an event.
2. Once the user adds/deletes a guest from the guests list.

Now I am facing a performance lag for the **second** scenario, can see **calendar.eventOpenTrigger** has been called multiple times when I am adding a new guest. Is there any to prevent multiple event triggering?

Manifest

```
"calendar": {
  "eventOpenTrigger": {
    "runFunction": "onCalendarEventOpen"
  },
  "currentEventAccess": "READ"
}
```

Trigger Function

```
 function onCalendarEventOpen(e) {
  console.log(e);
  if(e.calendar.attendees) {
    var emails = e.calendar.attendees.map(attendee => attendee.email);
    if(emails.length > 0) {
      var w2pData = w2pClient().getUsersList(emails);
      return buildW2pCommunicationCard(w2pData);
    } else {
      return createHomeCard();
    }
  } else {
    return createHomeCard();
  }
}
```

Log

[image]

Comment: Hi there @DilipTharuka! To better study this behaviour, could you please share the trigger code? Also please clarify if the event is highly populated by guests.

Comment: Yes, this is triggered only by guests, I don't think it's because of trigger code, coz when I put only console.log() for trigger code, it is also called three-four times when a guest is added. Anyway, my trigger code is also attached.

Comment: Confirmed - calendar event does indeed fire several times when trying to add a guest. Removal of a guest fires only once as expected. Probably a bug. Worth reporting to issue tracker

Comment: Done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172947241

Comment: @OlegValter any solution that I can do inside the `onCalendarEventOpen` function to accept one event and ignore other events?

Comment:  @DilipTharuka - no, I do not think there is anything you can do to prevent that *for sure*. But since the events fire in rapid succession you can use `Lock` or use `CacheService` to cache a temporary value and check for it when running the trigger. Actually, locking should take care of the issue. Interesting whether this is intended or a bug. Seems to me that an edit event should fire once.